# Recreate log file

Tags: sql-server

Taken database to offline and deleted the log file.
While take back database online will recreate log file automatically
But in my case it is not. Please suggest way to create primary log file at this situation.

Comment: What is MS SQL Server version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the CREATE DATABASE command using FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG option. It does require a clean shutdown so you cross your fingers that the offline was considered a clean shutdown. Basic syntax:

> CREATE DATABASE [name] ON (FILENAME = [path to mdf]) FOR
>   ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG

We do not recommend deleting transaction log file, for very good reasons. I hope you will be able to recover from this with less than performing a restore from your most recent backup.